# Display number of Mercurial commits in a named branch

Tags: mercurial

I am using a combination of the `id --num --rev tip` command and a small CMake script to generate a build number for a library.

It all works but the canonical version of the library lives in its own "vendor" branch so I need to be able to execute `id --num --rev tip` with a parameter that tells it to look in a different branch from default.

All my attempts have failed - is this possible and if so, what is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Uh, none of those! Do **NOT** use the numerical revision in a mercurial repository in order to do versioning. The **numerical revision number is strictly local to an individual repository** and can even change when you do a local clone.

I very much recommend to use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) and possibly counting the commits since the last such tag. Your friend for these efforts are [revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) and [templating](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/templates) which allow you access to these (checkout also `hg help revsets` and `hg help templates`).

E.g.

```
hg log --rev="last(branch(BRANCHNAME))" --template"{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}"
```

That gives for one of my repositories in default `0.4.4-11` and 0.2 branch `0.2.5-1` respectively. If you want a specific version instead of the latest in the given branch, just replace the `--rev`-argument with the actual revision you are interested in.

Mind that in the above form there is still ambiguity if you work with branches which have several heads which branch after a tag made to it; thus there really is no good way around using the commit hashes in any versioning scheme. Thus for the currently checked-out version I usually use as version:

```
 hg log -r. --template="{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance} (h{node|short})"
```

which gives me `0.4.4-11 (h96b8395ca393)`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @planetmaker - I have a lot to learn about Mercurial.Going forwards, I think the right way to generate a build number for my use case is an external C++ app the inserts a monotonically increasing value into the version header - "days since first commit" - or something like that.

Comment: Consider using the time information of the commit - however that is not necessarily sequential either as a commit can be made 2 weeks ago, but is only pushed to your repo now. However if your commit sequence is not tremendously high you can live with the unix time: `hg log -r. -T"{date|hgdate}"`

Comment: I tried for a very long time to find the sequential versioning for distributed repositories which works for basically all cases. Unless you have an authorative repository from which you build all your artefacts, and you live with the fact that building it from another, non-authorative repo may yield a different result, you will not get a strictly linear versioning, whatever you do. Thus my (strong) recommendation is: don't go for a linear versioning scheme, it works with svn, but leads to tears with distributed VCS :) Use tags for your releases, and something like above for development builds.